# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree con npm install

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Estoy tratando de instalar todas las dependencias npm de un proyecto anterior a un nuevo proyecto, para eso copié el *package.json* del proyecto anterior al nuevo proyecto, pero al momento de ejecutar `npm install` me devuelve el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté ejecutar el comando con `--force` o `--legacy-per-deps` como indican en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages), pero no funciona.

Mi versión de node es **16.17.1**.

Answer (score 1):

Si hay dos paquetes que tienen una dependencia, pero la versión requerida de cada uno es distinta, npm no sabe cuál de las dos instalar porque a un paquete no le sirve la del otro.
Deben estar fijadas las versiones en el *package.json*.

Para ver paquetes desactualizados: [npm outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-outdated)

Si sospechas qué paquetes pueden estar generando el error, la consola de npm suele explicarlo muy bien, prueba a cambiar la versión de alguno.

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
}
```

Así instalas las últimas versiones.

Si no puedes cambiar las versiones, cópiate tambien el *package-lock.json* y ejecuta de nuevo `npm install`, ahí es donde se guarda el árbol de dependencias pero en vez de tratar de adivinarlo, lo lee del *lock.json*.